# How to fix this circular reference error involving Protocols and type aliases?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols

The below code snippet, which is taken from this [Github issue](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/61152#issue-1375841385), fails to compile on Xcode 14.1

```
enum GenericState<Mode>: Hashable where Mode: Hashable {}

// error: Circular reference
protocol P {
  associatedtype Mode: Hashable
  // (false positive error) - Type 'Self.Mode' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
  typealias SomeState = GenericState<Mode>

  typealias Foo = [CustomKeyPath<Self, String>]
  
  
}

struct Interface<Base> where Base: P {}
typealias CustomKeyPath<Base, T> = KeyPath<Interface<Base>, T> where Base: P
```

See screenshot of errors:
[image: error screenshot]

So, apparently, the latest swift update has some issues with Circular references.

How should I go about fixing these errors?

Comment: Your protocol is for NSManagedObject sub-classes so why does it redefine part of the NSManagedObject interface? This makes very little sense to me. All the properties and the init are already defined in NSManagedObject

Comment: `public protocol FHEntity: NSManagedObject` compiles fine on my Xcode 14.1. BTW, any reasons you're still using the deprecated `class` keyword?

Comment: Your original code also compiles on my side...

Comment: @Cristik If I use your code, I get this error on typealias line: 'Type 'Self' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'.

Comment: @Cristik have you used complete code of the protocol or just the above line?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is there from the very beginning and i don't know why it was setup that way. The only thing important for me is how to run my code on latest Xcode.

Comment: I removed `:class` and it compiles fine for me too. I guess there is something else involved here.

Comment: Did you delete the DerivedData folder and clean the build folder after upgrading to v14?

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting the DereivedData folder and cleaned my build folder multiple times and then tried to build but it says now: "Type 'Self' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just used the above code in a new sample project (using Xcode 14.1) and it compiles without any issues. 
This protocol code in my project is inside a framework. Maybe that is causing the problem then?

Comment: You have a type alias inside the protocol that uses a type alias defined outside the protocol that refers to the protocol in its declaration, hence the circular reference. If you remove those 2 type alias all compiler errors go away. Since I don't understand the use case for those 2 declarations I can not suggest any solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please see this issue on Apple/swift Github repo:
https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/61152